# What is the sum of this series: $\sum_{n>=1}{(-1)^{n+1}*\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the sum of this series: $$\sum_{n>=1}{(-1)^{n+1}*\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}}$$
I don't know how to solve it especialy with that ${(-1)^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

1.$(-1)^{n+1}*\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}=(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1})$

and

2. $ \sum_{n \ge 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}= \ln (2)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ is even. Write the sum of two consecutive elements of your sum:
$$\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{2n+3}{(n+2)(n+1)} = \frac{2}{n(n+2)} = \frac 1n - \frac{1}{n+2}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I allready did that but what i do with that ${(-1)^{n+1}}$

Comment: @NeacsuMihai we've already handled that: $$a_n+a_{n+1} = (-1)^n\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)} +(-1)^{n+1} \frac{2n+3}{(n+2)(n+1)} = \frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{2n+3}{(n+2)(n+1)}.$$